# ADF pipeline changes required on enabling hierarchical namespaces in Azure Data Lake Gen2

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

What are the changes that will be required in the ADF pipeline on enabling hierarchical namespaces in Azure Data Lake Gen2.
What improvements can be expected in ADF and Synapse once this upgrade is done.
The datalake is used to store raw data

Upgrade to a storage account with Azure Data Lake Gen2 capabilities, but need to know the impact on existing pipelines and data flows in ADF
[Enabling Hierarchical Namespaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0oyF.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are several implementation details that would impact existing pipelines and code assets.

1. Blob Storage and ADLS (Gen2) have different Linked Service types, so you would need to create a new Linked Service and update all items that reference the old Blob Storage Linked Service (typically Datasets).
2. The URL paths and protocols are different:

- The root blob storage URL format is
  *{storage-account-name}.blob.core.windows.net*. For ADLS, the
  format is *{storage-account-name}.dfs.core.windows.net*.
- For services that require the custom system driver (such as Spark notebooks), Blob Storage uses *wasbs* for the protocol. ADLS uses *abfss*.

3. ADLS typically requires better defined IAM/RBAC. You will most likely need to grant the StorageBlobDataReader or StorageBlobDataContributor role to the Managed Identity for your ADF instance. When you create an ADLS Linked Service, I believe the UI gives you a prompt to remind you to add that role.

Answer (score 0):

One improvement with HNS is when you are doing parallel copies into ADLS, such as when the executions are happening at the same time, sometimes without HNS these resulted in errors in my experience. Without HNS, static folders had to be used, in the sense that parallel copies only copied into different folders and not the same one at the same time (imagine 50 copy activities running in parallel).

From that point of view, Gen2 with HNS is a better option than for example using a blob storage.

There are differences in ACL too, that might be beneficial for ADF/Synapse.

From documentation (Atomic Directory Manipulation):

"Without real directories, applications must process potentially millions of individual blobs to achieve directory-level tasks. By contrast, a hierarchical namespace processes these tasks by updating a single entry (the parent directory).

This dramatic optimization is especially significant for many big data analytics frameworks. Tools like Hive, Spark, etc. often write output to temporary locations and then rename the location at the conclusion of the job. Without a hierarchical namespace, this rename can often take longer than the analytics process itself. Lower job latency equals lower total cost of ownership (TCO) for analytics workloads."

In short, this method of blob organization greatly enhances the performance of search operations. Here is simple illustration from one my books which shows how ADLS search improves upon blob storage:

[image: ADLS Gen2 layer on top of Blob]

That being said, of course not all workloads are going to benefit from HNS, but workloads for analytics processing is especially to benefit a lot from HNS. What is the workload/processing you have in mind?